# Creating WCF DataContracts dynamically from code

Tags: wcf, dynamic, datacontract, icustomtypedescriptor

Given the fact that I have a fully dynamic object model, that is, I have no concrete classes defined anywhere in code, but I still want to be able to create WCF DataContracts for them so I can use them in operations. How can I achieve this?

My concrete class "Entity" implements ICustomTypeDescriptor which is used to present the various properties to the outside world, but my expeimentation with WCF suggests that WCF does not care about ICustomTypeDescriptor. Is this correct or have I missed something?

Is this possible? It cannot be so that the only way to create a DataContract is to actually have a concrete harcoded class, can it?

Comment: To clarify, I have metadata defined for i.e. a Car, a Building, a Company or whatever and it is that metadata that is presented using ICustomTypeDescriptor on the actual Entity instance.

Comment: To further clarify, I can absolutley decorate my Entity class with DataContract, however I need to have WCF look att the properties of the Entity using my ICustomTypeDescriptor. Is This possible?

Comment: Hi Fredrik. Even if you could dynamically generate the datacontracts, I would ask the question - should you be doing this at all. How are you going to ensure that consumers of your services are not going to get break if your generated domain model changes? I'd strongly recommend you map your generated domain model into strongly typed DTO's and send them across your services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things evolve :-) Thanks to the [excellent blog series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/creating-a-data-service-provider-part-1-intro) by Alex D James its very easy to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

you may use untyped service and message contract IIRC [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20161108121405/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/claeyskurt/archive/2008/09/24/125430.aspx)

Comment: But in that sample it seams the message still uses an internal class that is decorated with [DataContract]. Ideally I would like consumers to see a service operation like:

Company GetCustomerByCustomerNumber( string customerNumber )

And this is of course possible using a [DataContract] decorated class called Company. But in my case I do not have an actual class for Company. 

I am able to add the operation by taking the ServiceHost and adding new Operations dynamically, so that part I have solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might try System.Reflection.Emit.

Its quite tricky, but essentially you will just build a custom run-time type, with decorated data contract attributes. It gets tricky when creating encapsulated properties with PropertyChanged notifications, but in your service layer you can just get away with auto properties which are a lot easier.

This dated, but still very relevant link should get you going in the right direction.
http://drdobbs.com/184416570